# Possibility to parallelize c++ nested for loop with CUDA /Investigation

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a C++ (CPP) file which is very cpu intensive, and has a lot of loops/iterations. It is compiled and wrapped to python as a shared object.  A doctor asked me if it could be parrallellised and to work out a draft version on a cheap GPU , before he would buy expensive stuff (I am a student). I've read and did some basic cuda, which is working, but don't know how to start now.
And it it possible to parallellize this.

This is the loop we are talking about:

```
vector<double> Calculate (vector< vector<double> >  Oricoor, int size_coor, vector< vector<double> > Property, string normalization, 
        vector<int> rotationStepList, float resolution, int beginProbe, int endProbe, vector<double> radius) {
    const int N_PROPERTIES = 4; 
    int size = rotationStepList.size(); 
    const int numberOfProbes = endProbe - beginProbe;

    //self.__getBox__(oricoor)
    vector< vector<double> > boxPoint = getBox(Oricoor, size_coor, resolution, radius);

    //self.__getEnergies__(oricoor, prop)
    vector<double> e = getEnergy(boxPoint, Oricoor, size_coor, Property, beginProbe, endProbe);

    //self.sphore = self.energy
    vector<double> sphore(N_PROPERTIES * numberOfProbes);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_PROPERTIES * numberOfProbes; ++i) {
        sphore[i] = e[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int rotationStep = rotationStepList[i];
        //cout << "Rotation Sterp: " << rotationStep << endl;
        for (int iTheta = 0; iTheta < 180; iTheta += rotationStep){
            double theta = 0.017453292519943 * iTheta;
            double cos_theta = cos(theta);
            double sin_theta = sin(theta);

            double rotateY[3][3] = {{cos_theta, 0, -sin_theta},
                {        0, 1,          0},
                {sin_theta, 0, cos_theta}};

            vector< vector<double> > Matrix_Y = dotMatrix(Oricoor, size_coor, rotateY);

            for (int iPsi = 0; iPsi < 360; iPsi += rotationStep) {
                double psi = 0.017453292519943 * iPsi;
                double cos_psi = cos(psi);
                double sin_psi = sin(psi);

                double rotateZ[3][3] = {{cos_psi, -sin_psi, 0},
                    {sin_psi,  cos_psi, 0},
                    {      0,        0, 1}};

                vector< vector<double> > Matrix_Z = dotMatrix(Matrix_Y, size_coor, rotateZ);

                for (int iPhi = 0; iPhi < 360; iPhi += rotationStep){
                    double phi = 0.017453292519943 * iPhi;
                    double cos_phi = cos(phi);
                    double sin_phi = sin(phi); 

                    double rotateX[3][3] = {{1,       0,        0},
                        {0, cos_phi, -sin_phi},
                        {0, sin_phi,  cos_phi}};

                    vector< vector<double> > Matrix_X = dotMatrix(Matrix_Z, size_coor, rotateX);
                    vector< vector<double> > boxP  = getBox(Matrix_X, size_coor, resolution, radius);

                    //self.__getEnergies__(oricoor, prop)
                    vector<double> energy = getEnergy(boxP, Matrix_X, size_coor, Property, beginProbe, endProbe); 

                    //self.sphore = self.energy
                    for (int a = 0; a < N_PROPERTIES * numberOfProbes; ++a) {
                        if (energy[a] < sphore[a]) {
                            sphore[a] = energy[a];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: Hi Talonmies, I saw already very interesting answers you gave. My question is, it is can be parallellised, and if yes, how i start

Comment: If my understanding is correct, then you basically just compute a bunch of values ("properties") for a lot of different coordinates (rotation angles). Unless I missed something, I'd say it looks like the computation of each of these properties is independent of the rest. So yes, this could be parallelized. If you'd gain anything from using CUDA here, however, is hard to say without knowing more about the concrete application…

Comment: Indeed, it is a computation of properties of a 3D model of a molecule. 
The thing i struggle with : I thought, for parallellisation, all calls/functions must be independent of eachother . What I see, the loops are linked together (Mattrix_Y, Matrix_Z, Matrix_Z). Is is possibe to parralize then?

Comment: As usual, profiling your code is the right way to identify bottlenecks. Maybe it's in dotMatrix, maybe it's in getEnergy, maybe it's in memory allocaion in your innermost loop. I strongly suggest you to 1. profile your code 2. write a simple reproducer we can actually compile and run

Comment: It is quite likely that there is a sensible way to GPU accelerate the calculations this code performs. It is also quite likely that there is no way to naively "parallelize" the code in the way you seen to be implying. As for how to start, I generally find that making a fresh pot of tea, putting on some Miles Davis, sitting down at the computer and typing some code is a great way  to start writing in CUDA

Comment: Thanks for the good hints and feedback. I just noticed the "parallelize" typo ;)
We already did some timings and iteration documentation, and in effect, the "GetEnergy" calculation takes about 75% of the time. So i want to look into solutions to put these calculations in parallel, as this can speed up things. I see they are in a loop together with the other 2 functions. Does anyone had to do some kind of function separation like this , and maybe some examples? thx for the help